# Is there transaction support (TransactionalOperator) for Spring Web Flux projects using Spring Data Neo4j?

Tags: kotlin, spring-webflux, spring-transactions, spring-data-neo4j

I tried using `TransactionalOperator` in the following component:

```
@Component
class OrganisationHandler(
    private val repository: OrganisationRepository,
    private val operator: TransactionalOperator
) { ... }
```

Starting the application results in the following error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 1 of constructor in com.keen.backend.organisation.OrganisationHandler required a bean of type 'org.springframework.transaction.reactive.TransactionalOperator' that could not be found.

The following candidates were found but could not be injected:
    - Bean method 'transactionalOperator' in 'TransactionAutoConfiguration' not loaded because @ConditionalOnSingleCandidate (types: org.springframework.transaction.ReactiveTransactionManager; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans


Action:

Consider revisiting the entries above or defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.transaction.reactive.TransactionalOperator' in your configuration.
```

I used [this documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.6.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/languages.html#transactions) as reference. I also stumbled upon [this blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2019/05/16/reactive-transactions-with-spring) from a year ago. It doesn't seem like there's any SDN implementation of `AbstractReactiveTransactionManager` to use with `TransactionalOperator#create(ReactiveTransactionManager)`. I couldn't find any relevant ticket on the feature either.

Is there a workaround or perhaps a different approach to transactions for SDN in a Web Flux environment?

Comment: you have not written what neo4j dependency you are using, but i think if you use `Spring Data Neo4j RX starter` https://neo4j.com/developer/spring-data-neo4j-rx/ you will get all transaction management for reactive. There seems to a lot of transaction classes in the git repo https://github.com/neo4j/sdn-rx/tree/master/spring-data-neo4j-rx/src/main/java/org/neo4j/springframework/data/core/transaction it says there "The Spring Data Neo4j Reactive library is new and a planned successor to the Spring Data Neo4j offering. Its feature benefit is the capability and support for reactive transactions"